# Mongodump of docker mongoDB instance to single timestamp named file

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, docker

I'm doing backup dump of a mongoDb docker instance (`mongo_db`) via docker-compose (thanks to Matt for that snippet so far):

```
  version: "3"
  services:
    mongo_db_backup:
      image: 'mongo:3.4'
      volumes:
        - '/backup:/backup'
      command: |
        mongodump --host mongo_db --out /backup/ --db specific
```

Executing the command

```
$ docker-compose run mongo_db_backup
```

gives me all collections of `specific` db and stores them in `/backup/specific`.

Is it possible to get only one single (compressed) dump file, which is named as current time?

I'm using `--out` to get the files in the folder. The docs are saying I cannot use `--archive` together with `--out`.

Further more I need to use a env variable to set the archive output. Something like this:

```
mongo_db_backup:
  image: 'mongo:3.4'
  volumes:
    - '/backup:/backup'
  command: 
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      mongodump
      --host mongo_db
      --gzip
      --db specific
      $$(
        if [ $TYPE = "hour" ]
        then echo "--archive=/backup/hour/$$(date +"%H").gz"
        elif [ $TYPE = "day" ]
        then echo --archive=/backup/day/$$(date +"%d").gz
        fi  
      )
```

Executing with `$ docker-compose run -e TYPE=day mongo_db_backup`

Comment: Try changing the command to `sh -c "mongodump --host mongo_db --gzip --archive=/backup/$$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") --db specific"`

Comment: Do I need the "|"?

Comment: Only if you put it in the next line. If you use `command: <command>` then it is not needed

Comment: Do I have to add the extension? `.gz`, right?

Comment: Please post your command as an answer. Is it possible, to pass a kind of variable to specify a collection? e.g. `docker-compose run mongo_db_backup cars` should run the command `sh -c ... --db specific -collection cars`. If parameter is missing, a complete dump should be done...

Comment: @user3142695 `|` provides a [literal](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#literal%20style/syntax) multi line block that acts like it is single quoted, so less unexpected stuff can happen, which is useful for complex shell commands and you can use `\` to seperate long commands into separate lines.

Comment: Yes, you can use. Will post answer in sometime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your compose to below

```
  version: "3"
  services:
    mongo_db_backup:
      image: 'mongo:3.4'
      volumes:
        - '/backup:/backup'
      command: sh -c "mongodump --host mongo_db --gzip --archive=/backup/$$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') --db $${DB:=specific}"
```

Now if you want to change the DB you can run it like below

```
docker-compose run -e DB=abc mongo_db_backup
```

If you want to use it like `docker-compose run mongo_db_backup abc` then would need to create `entrypoint.sh` script handle the arguments in that. So it is easier to do it using environment variables

**Edit-1 - Default behavior on missing environment variable**

If you need to change the command based on environment variable being specified or not, you can change the command to below

```
command: sh -c "mongodump --host mongo_db --gzip --archive=/backup/$$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') $$(if [ -z $DB ]; then echo '--db default_db'; else  echo --collection $DB; fi)"
```

**Edit-2: Multiline line command in compose with if else**

To solve the issue of using multiline commands in compose you need to use a combination of array and multiline

```
command:
  - sh
  - -c
  - |
    multi line shell script
```

Below is the command I worked out for your update

```
command:
  - bash
  - -c
  - |
    TYPE=$${TYPE:=day}
    if [ ! -d /backup/hour ]; then mkdir /backup/hour; fi
    if [ ! -d /backup/day ]; then mkdir /backup/day; fi

    mongodump --host mongo_db --gzip \
    --db test \
    $$( \
      if [ "$$TYPE" == "hour" ]; then \
         echo "--archive=/backup/hour/$$(date +'%H').gz"; \
      elif [ "$$TYPE" == "day" ]; then \
         echo "--archive=/backup/day/$$(date +'%d').gz"; \
      fi \
    )
```

Since docker-compose processes variables we need to escape each `$` using `$$`. So `$TYPE` becomes `$$TYPE`. Also `mongodump` is a single command, so if you split it into multiple lines you need to use `\` for multiline command continuation

Comment: Perfect. What would happen if the env variable is not set? Would use that to set a specific collection (not database). And if no collection is set by env variable, a complete dump should be done...

Comment: No, i added it to take a default value `specific` for DB name. If you need to do these things then best would be to a dump scripts which can handle such situations

Comment: Could you show me please a little example for such a dump script? Only to set the --collection option. That would be really great!

Comment: @user3142695, added a sample without bash script. You can customize it based on your needs

Comment: Thank you very much. How do I write that command in multiline in yml file?

Comment: See if this helps you https://github.com/docker-library/redmine/issues/52

Comment: I've updated my post with the command I was trying. But it seams to be wrong... :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155445/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-user3142695).